# How to share variables to all views (including behavior) in twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have this controller action:

```
   public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $start = $request->get('start', 0);
        $limit = $request->get('limit', 10);
        $articles = $this->articleRepository->all($start, $limit);
        $navigation = $this->menu->build()->render(new RenderStrategyBootstrap4());

        return $this->render('article/index.html.twig', [
            'articles' => $articles,
            'navigation'=>$navigation
        ]);
    }
```

I build a menu with:

```
$navigation = $this->menu->build()->render(new RenderStrategyBootstrap4());
```

Now this is high level behavior and I do not want to render this for every action there is. Is there a way in Symfony to move this behavior to a sort of view composer (like in Laravel?) and then share the variable with the view?

Or is there no way and do I need to create a base controller?

Comment: You can always register [globals](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html) as well in twig

Comment: [Embedded controllers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html) are one approach.

Comment: Embedded controllers work with subrequests though, which do carry some overhead like triggering event listeners and so on. Depending on the use-case this might even be desired but one should know about it to make the right choice (just leaving this here to help any decision when choosing which way is the most suitable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Custom Twig Extension as described here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html

There you can register a custom Twig Function like this:

```
public function getFunctions()
{
    return array('renderNavigation' => new TwigFunction(
              'renderNavigation',
              array($this, 'renderNavigation'),
              array('needs_environment' => true, 'is_safe' => array('html'))
           );
}

public function renderNavigation(Environment $twig)
{
    /* ... */
    return $twig->render(/* ... */);
}
```

Then you can use the function in every template like `{{ renderNavigation() }}`

Since the Twig Extension itself is a service you can inject whatever service else you need (like RequestStack, EntityManager and so on) and even cache expensive operations within the extension if you need to function to be run more than once.